# Skipping previously passed test in pytest

Tags: pytest

How do I skip previously passed test in pytest? It seems simple and certain plugins such as flake8 do it. I looked at the command line arguments and it doesn't seem that there is an easy flag, am I missing something? Thank you!

Edit: looks like flake8 have their own ignore cache that is used. I guess i'll need to write my own plugin that caches which files were checked.. unless somebody wrote such a plugin already?

Comment: I see, is there a convenient plugin someone made for this? I imagine i can just save a config file somewhere. I know flake8 plugin (https://pypi.org/project/pytest-flake8/) does something similar (skips flake8 test if it passed last time and file hash didn't change). I. guess i'll read their source.

Comment: Read the source, it relied on flake8 config and cache. I guess I need to make my own unless there is an existing plugin for this.

Comment: Use [cache mechanism](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html), the approach would be the same as when `pytest` stores the last failed tests.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks! If you want, make an answer with this and I'll mark it. I have requirements slightly more complicated than just running last failed, but config.cache basically does what I need and is parallel to pytest-flake8 code (which imports it from flake8 rather than pytest, didn't realize pytest also has it).